# everything but a pattern regex

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to use a regex to extract a portion of a string.

My string looks like so: `sometext[pattern]moretext[pattern]somemoretext`
and I want my regex to return me everything `BUT` the text in the pattern.

So the expected return is: `sometextmoretextsomemoretext`

I can match my pattern with this regex: `\[[a-z]+\]/g`

And I've been reading about javascript lookarounds,

so I thought I could do something like: `(?!(\[[a-z]+\]))/g`

But that returns something a little strange: ["", "", "" ...]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use [`.replace(/\[[^\]]*]/g, '')`](https://www.regex101.com/r/D26fZW/1)

Comment: oh wow thanks! didn't think about it, was trying to learn regexes :)

Comment: [Learning Regular Expressions](//stackoverflow.com/q/4736)